# How to simply post javascript data to PHP with HTML form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have this in my *javascript* code:

```
var data = signaturePad.toDataURL('image/png');
document.write(data);
```

the output looks slimier to that:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAZAAAADICAYAAADGFbfiAAAHFklEQVR4Xu3VsQ0AAAjDMPr/0/yQ2exdLKTsHAECBAgQCAILGxMCBAgQIHAC4gkIECBAIAkISGIzIkCAAAEB8QMECB...
```

Instead of `document.write(data);` I want to post the data to the self page by using a simple HTML form with hidden filed that can hold the data from JS. then, I want to use PHP to handle `$_POST` and store the data in a variable...

```
<?php 
// check for form submission...
if(isset($_POST['send'])) {
  // get the data
  $data = $_POST['data'];
}
?>
```

HTML form:

```
<form method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="data" value="">
  <input type="submit" name="send" value="submit">
</form>
```

I understand that I can somehow do it with AJAX but I couldn't figure out with the form, how should I get this done?

I guess that I'm looking for 2 solutions - first, how to use the form with JS to store the data in the hidden field and afterwords, maybe how to post it via AJAX to PHP if it can't be just posted to the same page...

Comment: there are 1000's of tutorials are there. https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Comment: you can change the value of your hidden data field using jquery and submit the form using ajax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot of ways to achieve this. In regards to the way you are asking, with a hidden form element.

change your form to:

```
<form method="post" name="myform" method="post" action="script.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="data" value="">
  <input type="submit" name="send" value="submit">
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
var data = signaturePad.toDataURL('image/png');
document.myform.data.value = data;
document.forms["myform"].submit();
```

Or Jquery:

```
var data = signaturePad.toDataURL('image/png');
$('form input[name="data"]').val(data);
$("form").submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
<?php
$data="<script>signaturePad.toDataURL('image/png')</script>";
?>
<form method="post">
 <input type="hidden" name="data" value="<?php echo $data; ?>">
 <input type="submit" name="send" value="submit">
</form>
```

works all the time.