# Passing javascript variable into html form

Tags: javascript, php, html

My goal is to delete item from db using html. Below is my code and wanted to know if I can pass the JS function or variable directly into html submit form?

```
<script>
function getstring() {
    document.getElementById("xyz");
}            
</script>
```

html

```
<form action="delete.php" method="post">

        <input type="submit" name="Test" value="getquery()"/>

 </form>
```

my question maybe confusing, but all I want to do is call the JS function or variable when clicking submit.

Comment: and what should your function do exactly? Whatever you do with JS it has nothing to do with deleting an item from your DB... at least not the way you portraited your problem - and with the provided code.

Comment: @ Roko C. Buljan Sorry haven't listed the entire code, anyways it's basically getting string which I want to pass. To make it more simple I just want to get the value from
document.getElementById("xyz"); and pass it into submit button.

Comment: the value of...?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to simply post javascript data to PHP with HTML form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44276182/how-to-simply-post-javascript-data-to-php-with-html-form)

Answer (score 1):

> *My goal is to delete item from db using html*

You don't need JS...

```
<form action="delete.php?id=33">
    <button>DELETE ITEM 33</button>
</form>
```

and in your PHP API for your `delete.php` you just need to

```
$id = $_GET["id"];  // "33"
// delete item ID $id in your database
```

Don't forget to make sure a GET SERVER REQUEST was received, $_GET["id"] is `isset()`  and by always sanitizing your values.

Comment: Thank you but it erros  ' Undefined index: data in delete.php". 

Trying to explain my situation here again:
"document.getElementById("xyz").innerHTML=(rows from table)" is fetching data from table. So if I do it outside of script tag like <pre id="xyz"></pre> it will show me string on my html page of selected row. 
Now I am trying to use that string to create my delete query and wanted to pass it to delete.php
So again using a form submit button I want to submit request which takes value from id="xyz" and pass it on delete.php. Please let me know if you have any solution.